# Which functions $f$ differentiable in all $\mathbb R$ satisfy $|f(x)| \geq |f'(x)|$ for all $x$ with $f(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

> Which functions $f$ differentiable in all $\mathbb R$ satisfy $|f(x)| \geq |f'(x)|$ for all $x$ with $f(0)=0$?

I'm pretty stuck right now. Any hint would be very helpfull.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$. Because $f$ is continuous, there exists an maximal interval $]a,b[$ containing $x_0$ (with $a$, $b$ eventually $-\infty$ or $+\infty$), such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in ]a,b[$. Moreover, because $f(0) = 0$, you can always choose that $f(a)=0$ **or** $f(b)=0$.

**Let's suppose that $f(a)=0$, and that $f$ is positive on $]a,b[$** (the other cases are similar). In particular, $f(x_0) > 0$.

You have then that for all $x \in [a,b]$, 
$$-f(x) \leq f'(x) \leq f(x)$$

Consider the function $g : [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$$

$g$ is differentiable and its derivative is given by $g'(x)=(f'(x)-f(x))e^{-x}$, which is always negative by asumption. So $g$ decreases, so for all $x \in [a,b]$, you have $g(x) \leq g(a)=0$. In particular $g(x_0) \leq 0$, so $f(x_0) \leq 0$.

But by asumption, you have $f(x_0) > 0$. Contradiction.

The other cases are similar, you get finally that there cannot exist such a $x_0$, so $f$ is the constant function equal to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, TheSilverDoe.